# Referencing Qt Widget into Other Python Class in Other file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have two Different Python Files. One is having GUI details and Another one is having Code to make a watch on Folder Using Watchdog API

GUI Py File :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'csvExcel.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from Main_File import Watcher, DataFrameTableWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.file_Name = None

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.start_button.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setFlat(False)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_button_click())
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.start_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Br_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Br_button.setObjectName("Br_button")
        self.Br_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browse_button())
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Br_button, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.start_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Start The Program"))
        self.start_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.Br_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse the File Location to Watch on"))
        self.Br_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sensor CSV To Excel"))

    def start_button_click(self):
        watcher = Watcher(self.file_Name)
        if self.start_button.text() == "Start":
            self.start_button.setText("Stop")
            w = DataFrameTableWidget(self.tableWidget)
            watcher.emitter.newDataFrameSignal.connect(w.append_dataframe)
            watcher.run()
        elif self.start_button.text() == "Stop":
            self.start_button.setText("Start")
            watcher.stop_watcher()

    def browse_button(self):
        self.file_Name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Open working directory', os.getcwd(), QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print(self.file_Name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Python Code File Having Watchdog Implementation

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
from Append_Function import append_df_to_excel


class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    newDataFrameSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pd.DataFrame)


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, filename)
        self.emitter = Emitter()
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(
            emitter=self.emitter,
            patterns=["*.CSV"],
            ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"],
            ignore_directories=True
        )

    def run(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop_watcher(self):
        self.observer.stop()


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, emitter=None, **kwargs):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._emitter = emitter
        self.file_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+".xlsx"

    def on_any_event(self, event):

        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)):

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1)

            else:
                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0)

            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            print("Modified created event - %s." % event.src_path)

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)):

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1)

            else:

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0)

            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)


class DataFrameTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(pd.DataFrame)
    def append_dataframe(self, df):
        df = df.copy()
        if df.columns.size > self.columnCount():
            self.setColumnCount(df.columns.size)
        r = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(r)
        for c, column in enumerate(df):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(column)

            self.setItem(r, c, it)
        i = self.rowCount()
        for r, row in df.iterrows():
            self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
            for c, (column, value) in enumerate(row.iteritems()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.setItem(i+r, c, it)
```

In This file you can See that I have used a function "Append_Function" That is Actually to append data into a Excel file(I will Edit to add Function Code if Needed).

**My Problem**

In the Watchdog Implementation file, you can see that there is a custom Pyslot in that DataFrameTableWidget Class. It gets Active when a Data frame is generated. and Accordingly, The data from the data frame is displayed in the QWidget table as The DataFrameTableWidget Class is inheriting the QTableWidget.

Now as you can See I have made a separate GUI for my Application having a table Widget. I want The data from pandas Data frame to be Displayed into my GUI table Widget instead of getting displayed into the QTableWidget that has been inherited by DataFrameTableWidget Class in my WatchDog Implementation File.

I am thinking that somehow initializing the DataFrameTableWidget Class with QTableWidget from GUI may work. But I am not sure if I can Pass QTableWidget to the DataFrameTaleWidget Class Initialization (ie. **init**) function so that I can Refer my GUI table Widget into my Watchdog Implementation File.

I tried my best to be clear with my problem here. But if still facing problem while understanding I will Edit and will try to make it more clear.

Thank you!

**Update Version of Code**

csvExcelGUI.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from Main_File import Watcher, DataFrameTableWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.file_Name = None

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.start_button.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setFlat(False)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")
        #self.start_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.start_button_click())
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.start_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Br_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Br_button.setObjectName("Br_button")
        self.Br_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browse_button())
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Br_button, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        #self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget = DataFrameTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.start_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Start The Program"))
        self.start_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.Br_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse the File Location to Watch on"))
        self.Br_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sensor CSV To Excel"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_button_click)
        self.watcher = Watcher()
        self.watcher.emitter.newDataFrameSignal.connect(self.tableWidget.append_dataframe)
        self.file_Name = ""

    def start_button_click(self):
        self.watcher.set_filename(self.file_Name)
        if self.start_button.text() == "Start":
            self.start_button.setText("Stop")
            self.watcher.run()
        elif self.start_button.text() == "Stop":
            self.start_button.setText("Start")
            self.watcher.stop_watcher()

    def browse_button(self):
        self.file_Name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Open working directory', os.getcwd(), QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print(self.file_Name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    # ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    # ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    # MainWindow.show()
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Main_File.py

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer
import time
from Append_Function import append_df_to_excel


class Emitter(QtCore.QObject):
    newDataFrameSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(pd.DataFrame)


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.directory_to_watch = None
        self.emitter = Emitter()
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(
            emitter=self.emitter,
            patterns=["*.CSV"],
            ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"],
            ignore_directories=True
        )

    def set_filename(self, filename):
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, filename)

    def run(self):
        self.observer.schedule(self.event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=False)
        self.observer.start()

    def stop_watcher(self):
        self.observer.stop()


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, emitter=None, **kwargs):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._emitter = emitter
        self.file_name = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")+".xlsx"

    def on_any_event(self, event):

        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)):

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1)

            else:
                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0)

            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            print("Modified created event - %s." % event.src_path)

            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name)):

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1)

            else:

                append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.file_name),
                                   pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0))
                df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0)

            self._emitter.newDataFrameSignal.emit(df.copy())
            df.set_index(df.columns.values.tolist()[0], inplace=True)


class DataFrameTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(pd.DataFrame)
    def append_dataframe(self, df):
        df = df.copy()
        if df.columns.size > self.columnCount():
            self.setColumnCount(df.columns.size)
        r = self.rowCount()
        self.insertRow(r)
        for c, column in enumerate(df):
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(column)

            self.setItem(r, c, it)
        i = self.rowCount()
        for r, row in df.iterrows():
            self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
            for c, (column, value) in enumerate(row.iteritems()):
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.setItem(i+r, c, it)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- With the line: `w = DataFrameTableWidget(self.tableWidget)`, you are only pointing out that Data Frame qTableWidget is the child of the QTableWidget (that is, it will be placed inside the widget), and will not replace it.
- `watcher = Watcher(self.file_Name)` is a local variable that will be deleted when it finishes executing start_button_click.

Assuming that your code works before adding the GUI, I will make the following modifications:

1. Change `self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)` by `self.tableWidget = DataFrameTableWidget(self.centralwidget)`, if you had the .ui it would teach you to use how to set new widgets through Qt Designer.
2. Implement a set_filename method so that there is no need to create a new Watcher object each time you press the button.
3. Make the object to the object watcher member of the class.

**Main_File.py**

```py
# ...

class Watcher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.emitter = Emitter()
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.event_handler = Handler(
            emitter=self.emitter,
            patterns=["*.CSV"],
            ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"],
            ignore_directories=True
        )
    def set_filename(self, filename):
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, filename)

    # ...
```

**main.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'csvExcel.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import os
from Main_File import Watcher, DataFrameTableWidget


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.start_button.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setDefault(False)
        self.start_button.setFlat(False)
        self.start_button.setObjectName("start_button")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.start_button, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Br_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Br_button.setObjectName("Br_button")
        self.Br_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.browse_button())
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Br_button, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.tableWidget = DataFrameTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 3, 0, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.start_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Start The Program"))
        self.start_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start"))
        self.Br_button.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse the File Location to Watch on"))
        self.Br_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sensor CSV To Excel"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_button_click)
        self.watcher = Watcher()
        self.watcher.emitter.newDataFrameSignal.connect(self.tableWidget.append_dataframe)
        self.file_Name = ""

    def start_button_click(self):
        self.watcher.set_filename(self.file_Name)
        if self.start_button.text() == "Start":
            self.start_button.setText("Stop")
            self.watcher.run()
        elif self.start_button.text() == "Stop":
            self.start_button.setText("Start")
            self.watcher.stop_watcher()

    def browse_button(self):
        self.file_Name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Open working directory', os.getcwd(), QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print(self.file_Name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "if you had the .ui it would teach you to use how to set new widgets through Qt Designer." By this, you mean creating Custom Widget?

Comment: @ViralParmar see this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6622587+[pyqt]+[qt-designer]+promote

Comment: After all this, I am Still Struggling with setting the table header. I refer to a UI Instance into My Main_file.py and tried giving df.columns.values to the table Widget but it's not working. Although this was not my question here.